# Push notification alert pop up is visible to user after opening application

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

When received multiple Push notification with the "Alerts" style in the Settings. After clicking Open on one of them other alerts is visible for upto 1 seconds even after I have cleared it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

How to clear all other notification once we click on Open?

Comment: I have tried to use following code but it is visible for upto 1 second and then it gets cleared. [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];